# C language, grouping elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays, grouping, element

My code is far too long, complicated and tedious for me to post it here, but suppose you had something like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

char myArray[3000]={3,1,3,1,2,5,1,1,7,0,1,3,0,1,2,0,1,6,0,1,8,9,1,0,0,1,4,3,1,7};
```

Suppose I wanted to make a new array that takes the two consecutive digits from the above list of elements.

indexes 2-6 of `myArray` contain (3,1,2,5), how can I get my new array to group elements and store elements 2-6 as (31, 25).

I'm new to programming and I haven't found an efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Iterate over the array and compute the value that belongs in the new array.  Then make an assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I'll need two iterative elements right?

Comment: If the value that goes in `new_array[i]` is dependent only on i and the values of myArray, then you just need to iterate over the index of the new array.

Comment: what do you mean by grouping elements? Arrays don't have groups inside them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to think about it:

```
int newArray[2];
newArray[0] = myArray[2]*10 + myArray[3];
newArray[1] = myArray[4]*10 + myArray[5];
```

If you wanted something more generic...

```
#define NEW_ARRAY_SIZE 5
int newArray[NEW_ARRAY_SIZE];
int offset = 2;
int i = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < NEW_ARRAY_SIZE; ++i )
{
   newArray[i] = myArray[offset+2*i]*10 + myArray[offset+2*i+1];
}
```

Comment: Mine's a char array, so I won't need the '*10' parts, only just to add the first character to the next, thanks.