# Grouping hexa array elements

Tags: arrays, c

I have a code that will convert decimal into hexa. After the conversion every 2 elements represent 1 hexa number for (example 120 is converted into 78, the 7 is an element and 8 is another element but they should be one element inside the array). I tried [C language, grouping elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364424/c-language-grouping-elements-in-an-array) but didn't work. I can probably stringfy the array and use strcat() with a loop unless there is a better way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NEW_ARRAY_SIZE 121
void ByteToASCII(char * string, unsigned char byte) {
    char curval;
    curval = (char)('0' | (byte >> 4));
    if ('9' < curval) {
        curval += (char)('A' - '9' - 1);
    }
    * string++ = curval;
    byte <<= 4;
    curval = (char)('0' | (byte >> 4));
    if ('9' < curval) {
        curval += (char)('A' - '9' - 1);
    }
    * string++ = curval;
    * string = 0;
}
int main(void) {
    //printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
    //scanf("%d", &num);
    unsigned char num [60] = {120, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 128, 31, 239, 31, 254, 1, 255, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 255, 192, 255, 255, 255, 128, 127, 231, 192, 120, 14, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    char hex_arr[(2 * sizeof(num)) + 1];
    for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(num); k++) {
        ByteToASCII( & hex_arr[k * 2], num[k]);
    }
    printf(hex_arr);

    //output(78FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000007F801FEF1FFE01FFF0000000007FFFC0FFFFFF807FE7C0780E00780000000000000000000000)

    printf("\n");

    char newArray[NEW_ARRAY_SIZE];
    char newArray1[NEW_ARRAY_SIZE];
    int offset = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NEW_ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        newArray[i] = hex_arr[offset + 2 * i];
        // output (7F00000000000000000000781E1F0FF00007FCFFF87EC700700000000000)
        newArray1[i] = hex_arr[offset + 2 * i + 1];
        //output (8F00000000000000000000F0FFFE1F00000FF0FFF0F708E0800000000000)

        // newArray[i] = hex_arr[offset+2*i] + hex_arr[offset+2*i+1]; // didnt work
    }
    printf(newArray);
    printf("\n");
    printf(newArray1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. There's no need for obscure arithmetic with ASCII values, type conversions and so on. I wouldn't try to salvage this function, instead implement a function converting any amount of data to a hex string. It only needs to do this:

- Mask out the upper nibble of each data byte.
- Mask out the lower nibble of each data byte.
- Do table-lookups.
- Find the correct index in the resulting string, which is found at a multiple index of x2.
- Null terminate.

---

Example:

```
void get_hexstr (char* dst, size_t size, uint8_t data[size])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    const char LOOKUP[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    uint8_t upper = (data[i]>>4)&0xF;
    uint8_t lower = data[i]&0xF;
    dst[i*2]   = LOOKUP [upper];
    dst[i*2+1] = LOOKUP [lower];
  }
  dst[size*2]='\0';
}
```

Test code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void get_hexstr (char* dst, size_t size, uint8_t data[size])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    uint8_t upper = (data[i]>>4)&0xF;
    uint8_t lower = data[i]&0xF;
    
    const char LOOKUP[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    
    dst[i*2]   = LOOKUP [upper];
    dst[i*2+1] = LOOKUP [lower];
  }
  
  dst[size*2]='\0';
}

int main (void)
{
  unsigned char num [60] = {120, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 128, 31, 239, 31, 254, 1, 255, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 255, 192, 255, 255, 255, 128, 127, 231, 192, 120, 14, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  char hex_arr[(2 * sizeof(num)) + 1];
  
  get_hexstr(hex_arr, 60, num);
  puts(hex_arr);
}
```